# Find the partial derivative of a composite function

Tags: functions

so I have two functions: $f(x,y) = (x^2,xy^2)$ and $y(u,v) = uv$. I need to calculate the $\frac{\partial y\circ f}{\partial x}(x,y)$.
 Right now I am trying to understand how the partial derivatives of composite function works, but I don't have any example in my book. So I was wondering if you cold help me with the solution for this one to have it as an example so that I will be able to solve other exercises of this kind.

Comment: It cannot be $y\circ f$ because $y$ takes two arguments and $f(x,y)$ is one number so $y(f(x,y))$ doesn’t make sense

Comment: Ok so now I've edited the question. Sorry for this.

Comment: $y \circ f$ is a function in $x, y$, after which you can apply the chain rule. Another example is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723582/partial-derivative-of-a-composite-function).

Answer (score 0):

Let’s do it the brutal way

$$y\circ f(x,y)=x^2\cdot xy^2=x^3y^2$$

And so

$${\partial(y\circ f)\over \partial x}(x,y)=3x^2y^2$$